# The function `(y * y) < x' is applied to two arguments, but its type `Bool' has none

Tags: haskell

So I am working on [Problem 31](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/99_questions/31_to_41).

I have written the following function in hopes to determine if a number is a prime:

```
isPrime :: Integer -> Bool

isPrime x = prime x 2
            where
            prime :: Integer -> Integer -> Bool
            prime x y | ((y*y) < x) and ((x `mod` y) /= 0) = prime x (y+1)
                      | ((y*y) >= x) = True
                      | otherwise = False
```

My logic was make an `isPrime` function, and have a function within `isPrime` called `prime` to store 2 parameters, the number I want to check to see if it is prime (`x`) and an iterator to check all the numbers below sqrt of x and see if they divide `x`. `prime` has 3 guards:

```
| ((y*y) < x) and ((x `mod` y) == 0) = prime x (y+1)
```

This line is supposed to say: is the number I passed less than the square root of x (`((y*y) < x)`) and if it is check if `x` is divisible by `y` (`((x`mod`y) /= 0)`), if it isn't I use recursion and increment y to check again with a higher number.

This line:

```
| ((y*y) >= x) = True
```

Is supposed to be like if all the numbers below the square root don't divide x in anyway, x must be prime.

Finally, this line:

```
| otherwise = False
```

means that a number somewhere along the line a number divided x so it is not prime.

I thought the code I wrote made sense, I know it isn't the most efficient, considering I could just check primes below sqrt x and not all the numbers below sqrt x, but anyways, I am having problems with this statement:

```
((y*y) < x)
```

GHCi says:

```
The function `(y * y) < x' is applied to two arguments, but its type `Bool' has none
```

I thought that the `<` was supposed to take in two arguments and return a Bool, the error message doesn't really make sense to me. Can you help me figure out what I am doing wrong? Thanks.

Quick edit now that I got it to run, this line:

```
| ((y*y) >= x) = True
```

should be:

```
| ((y*y) > x) = True
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

To explain what's happening here... the problem isn't with `<`, it's with the whole expression:

```
((y*y) < x) and ((x `mod` y) /= 0)
```

What you're missing is the backticks around `and`:

```
((y*y) < x) `and` ((x `mod` y) /= 0)
```

When you use a function infix like that, if it isn't an operator (i.e. made of symbols, like `++`), then you need to surround it with backticks.

Alternately, you can use it non-infix as a function, like:

```
and ((y*y) < x) ((x `mod` y) /= 0)
```

Now to explain the error message. What the compiler is saying is that you're trying to use the expression `((y*y) < x)` as a function. Since function application in Haskell doesn't use brackets, anything like `f x y` is a function `f` applied to two arguments `x` and `y`.

Since you forgot to put backticks around the `and`, Haskell interprets `` ((y*y) < x) and ((x `mod` y) /= 0) `` as you trying to apply the function `((y*y) < x)` to the arguments `and` and `` ((x `mod` y) /= 0) ``. Of course, this doesn't work, because `((y*y) < x)` returns `Bool`, which isn't a function, so it complains with "The function `(y * y) < x` is applied to two arguments, but its type `Bool` has none". `Bool` isn't a function type, and so it has no arguments.

...

Of course, the other error you have now is that it should be `&&` not `and` - `and` has type `[Bool] -> Bool`.

Comment: Urgh. Anyone know how to include backticks inside backticks on SO? I can't seem to escape them.

Comment: `&&` is the function for "logical and", with type `Bool -> Bool -> Bool`. `and` is a similar function with type `[Bool] -> Bool`, so putting backticks around it won't help here.

Comment: @Porges: Fixed that for you. So far as I know, you need to use `<code>...</code>` with backslash-escaped backticks inside.

Comment: You can just surround a string with backticks with two backticks to format it as code.

Comment: @Ben: did you read the whole thing? That's what the last bit says.

Answer (score 10):

I think you mean to use `&&` rather than `and`.  After doing that it loads without any errors.

Comment: Mother of god it runs now. I've been scratching my head on why the heck it doesn't work, I'm surprised it doesn't give me something like `and` isn't recognized or something like that. Oh, side note I made a slight error in my algorithm: `| ((y*y) >= x) = True` should be: `| ((y*y) > x) = True`

Comment: @anon: `and` is also a function, but it does something else.

Comment: @anon: `and` is recognized — it's just that it's not an infix operator. `and` is a function that takes a list and returns whether all of the elements in that list are `True`. What Haskell thought you were trying to do was apply the function `(y * y) < x` with an argument of the `and` function. `(y * y) < x` is not a function, so it fails.

Comment: @anon `and` is recognised; it's a function with type `[Bool] -> Bool`. It would be possible to have a function with type `([Bool] -> Bool) -> Bool -> Bool`, which is the type that would be needed at the position of your `(y * y) < x` expression. So a message about using an expression of type Bool really is the most accurate error the compiler can give you here; it's the only thing that's wrong.